# Feature detectors and descriptor takes significantly longer to compute in the first instance

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I am using [OpenCV's Feature2D::detectAndCompute()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d13/classcv_1_1Feature2D.html#a8be0d1c20b08eb867184b8d74c15a677) to compute the keypoints and descriptors of images.

The code basically look like this:

```
 Ptr<cv::ORB> orb = cv::ORB::create();
 Mat descriptors1, descriptors2...;
 vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2...;
 orb->detectAndCompute(img1, noArray(), keypoints1, descriptors1);  // first instance
 orb->detectAndCompute(img2, noArray(), keypoints2, descriptors2);  // second instance
 // more detectAndCompute...
```

My problem is that it takes significantly longer to do the first detectAndCompute(~0.25s) than all the detectAndCompute after it(~0.002s each). Why is this happening?

Also, regardless of how small the images are. The first detectAndCompute always takes 0.25s. Is there any way to cut down this time?

Thank you!

Comment: compute it once before your actual data arrives (initialization)

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate on that?

Comment: during your application's initialization, you could perform a first detectAndCompute call on some dummy images, before any actual relevant images arrive. Then you will have 0.002s with your first relevant image, but your initialization will need additional 0.25s. Whether this is possble obviously depends on your application/task, but in most cases such an approach is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it and it works! I am still curious about why is this a thing though.

Comment: hardware optimizations might be searched/tested at runtime, buffers have to be allocated, etc. Extreme initialization time is often seen for cuda applications, for example. Not sure about the actual reason in that function, though. Maybe SSE instruction set fixing? no idea...